# :help - is there something like apropos?

Tags: help-system

A very helpful comment led me to investigate `:help mode-switching` where after typing `:help mode` I used autocomplete to explore which additional help topics contained `mode`.

This was a very large number and now I wonder if `:help` provides something like `apropos`: return a list of all topics that contain a certain word in their title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for `:helpgrep`, which is mentioned in `:help helphelp`.

Comment: To get the actual list I additionally need `:cwindow`, it seems.

Comment: Well it fills the quickfix list @guntbert ; there is a location list variant as well.

Comment: btw: your improvements to my edit suggestions are not lost on me - I learn from them :+1

Comment: @guntbert  glad to hear it! I for one am glad to see your touch-ups (even to old Qs), but I generally think edits are most useful if, while correcting (for example) a spelling mistake, I go over the rest of the post for formatting, clarity, etc.

Comment: I am certainly used to doing just that - but there are some nuances to the preferred style between different SE sites and I try to follow the fate of most of my suggestions - thx for being so thorough and for your patience.

Comment: @guntbert ofc!!

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @DBenKnoble answer, in VimHelp the asterisks are normally used to mark topics. So you can do

```
:helpgrep *mode-
```

To eliminate the most of "false positives".